# How would the OS Handle Swap being turned off if it is being used?

Tags: debian, swap

So, I have a 10GB swap running on my server which handles numerous long running processes. I wanted to increase the swap size, as RAM is running almost 100% at times with > 3/4 of swap being used.

As an interim solution, I added a second swap disk with an increased amount of space on it, and increased its priority, so that it could take over the load over the weekend, with the one that is running low being decommissioned.

My question now is, I have processes which have been running between 6 - 17 days, which are critical to complete.

At the moment, there is enough space to cover any deficit if the old 10GB swap disk is removed (via `swapoff`), however, if one of the long running processes are using some of that swap space, would it kill that process? Or would the OS handle it and redistribute?

I'm running Debian 10 on Google Cloud Compute Engine VM host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel will handle this just fine: `swapoff` will cause pages from the removed swap to be moved back into physical memory, and then if necessary moved back out to (a non-disabled) swap device. No process should die as a result, as long as the remaining physical memory and enabled swap is sufficient to store the working set.